# My rock paper scissors game is not working, the value of variable userChoice remains unchanged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a simple program that takes input from the user by clicking the image of their choice. But here, the value of variable userChoice remains "undefined" even when it has been given a value.

Initially there was a problem that the code executed everything except the event listener part. Then, on applying condition it does waits for user input but the value of userChoice remains "undefined".

The link to my repository : https://github.com/Anmol270900/Rock-Paper-Scissors
It is deployed at : https://anmol270900.github.io/Rock-Paper-Scissors/

Expected : The code should have taken the input value and must have processed the desired result.
Actual : The userChoice is not taking the desired value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usChoice() is creating the event listeners. That's where the code is getting executed when you make a choice --> That is where you need to call your compChoice and your compare

Basically, each time the user click on one of the button, your event is triggered and only the code inside of the listener is executed

```
rock.addEventListener("click", () => {
    userChoice = "rock";
    alert("you chose rock");
    console.log(userChoice);
    computerChoice = compChoice();
    alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
});
```

should do the trick. (Apply to each listener)

I let you think about some refactoring :) to have a neater code.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Welcome! Be sure to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some background on how to write questions!

it seems you are comparing moves too early. Your function `usChoice()` only sets up the event listeners for the rock, paper and scissors and then starts comparing the value to the computer's move. You should let the computer move and compare after the user has made their choice, i.e., in the click handlers.

Change this

```
usChoice();

// Remove this
//    if(userChoice !== undefined)
//    {
//        computerChoice = compChoice();
//        alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
//    }
```

And this

```
paper.addEventListener("click", () => {
    userChoice = "paper";
    alert("you chose paper");
    console.log(userChoice);
    //return "paper";

    // Move it to here
    computerChoice = compChoice();
    alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
});
```

Then, refactor. Good luck!